# Use HtmlUnit to search google

Tags: htmlunit

The following code is an attempt to search google, and return the results as text or html.
The code was almost entirely copied directly from code snippets online, and i see no reason for it to not return results from the search. How do you return google search results, using htmlunit to submit the search query, without a browser?

```
      import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
      import java.io.*;
      import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;    
      import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput;
      import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;


      import java.net.*;

       public class GoogleSearch {

      public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException, MalformedURLException
      {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");
        HtmlInput input1 = page1.getElementByName("q");
        input1.setValueAttribute("yarn");

        HtmlSubmitInput submit1 = page1.getElementByName("btnK");

        page1=submit1.click();

        System.out.println(page1.asXml()); 

        webClient.closeAllWindows();
      }
    }
```

Comment: You could perhaps tell us what the program does. We know what it should do, but not what it does. Any exception? stack trace?

Comment: it runs, builds fine, without exceptions, but doesn't print out the xml/html. btnG works, and not sure why firefox sees a btnK where there should be a btnG. it could also be a prb with the parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be some browser detection that changes the generated HTML, because when inspecting the HTML with `page1.getWebResponse().getContentAsString()`, the submit button is named `btnG` and not `btnK` (which is not what I observe in Firefox). Make this change, and the result will be the expected one.

Comment: The first thing I do anytime I get a weird result is print `page1.asXml()` to the console... invariably the HTML is not QUITE what I think it is...

Comment: yes it was the browser detection, btnK is not the name google uses for its submit button, but it is in the html source using firefox. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked this. It's actually 2 ids for 2 google pages:

- btnK: on the google home page (where there's 1 long textbox in the middle of the screen). This time the button's id = 'gbqfa'
- btnG: on the google result page (where the main textbox is on top of the screen). This time the button's id = 'gbqfb'